# Get the expected rendered size of containing element from canvas.measureText?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, rendering

I get TextMetrics for the text in a DOM element (`position: absolut/fixed; display: block;`) before it is attached to the document like this:

```js
function getTextMetrics(txt, font) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    const tm = context.measureText(txt);
    return tm;
}
```

Looking at `tm` I can not understand how I get the rendered height/width. Something seems to be missing. What?

Yes, there are fields in the TextMetric returned that nearly fits, but they does not equal the .clientWidth/Height of the later rendered element.

There is no need to create a "working example" for this. It is too simple. Here are instead some figures (from Google Chrome, the values @ggorlen mentions does not exist there):

```
   .clientWidth: 82
   .clientHeight: 20

   tm:
   width : 73.2734375
   fontBoundingBoxAscent : 16
   fontBoundingBoxDescent : 3
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? Looking at [`TextMetrics`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics), there's a `.width` and `.emHeightAscent`/`.emHeightDescent`. I'm not sure what you expect to be there that you think isn't. What do you mean by the "rendered" height/width as opposed to just the height/width?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. tm should contain the width of your text, the height can be determined in various ways... I really don't understand your question though, you mention that you are attaching a DOM element... Is there a particular reason  you need the size before rendering the element?

Comment: @SharpDev Rendering is async. The sizes are needed for layout. (It is a mindmap.)

Comment: @ggorlen .width is not exactly equal to .clientWidth after rendering. And .emHeightAscent/Descent does not equal .clientHeight if you add them.

Comment: What do you mean by "after rendering"? There's no rendering going on in the code here. `txt` is measured but never drawn on the canvas. I think a runnable [mcve] would go a long way to clarifying what you mean here, and we're still missing context of your high level goal. What sort of user-visible behavior are you trying to implement? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen "after rendering" is a bit technical. The browser screen rendering and the JavaScript engine are not synced. Rendering happens later. (You will only notice this if you are doing some more difficult things with layout.)

Comment: What `.clientWidth` are you accessing? What difficult things are you doing with layout? I'll leave it at this... I don't want to nitpick forever, but I think you're expecting someone who _Just Knows_ what you're doing/talking about rather than taking the time to enumerate the situation from the ground up, step by step, reproducibly, with context (which is the site standard, I might add).

Comment: The .clientWidth of the element that contains just the text. (The layout problem I am trying to solve is not necessary to dig into here. If you are interested then take a look at jsMind on GitHub. I am working on a fork of that.)

Comment: As I understand it by your statements @Leo you want a method to synchronously get the rendered width and height before the main content is rendered.... If this is the case, then you don't need canvas.measureText (and I would avoid it)... Is it fine if I solve your problem another way which does utilize the DOM?

Comment: "`.clientWidth` of the element that contains just the text"--where is this element? If it has CSS applied, maybe that accounts for the discrepancy? What browser(s)?

Comment: The figures I added in EDIT 2 are measured when the element has been added to the DOM. I'm using Google Chrome. In the Dev Tools I can see no padding. Anything else I should look for? (You removed the words "EDIT 2", but I am sure you understand what I mean.)

Comment: @SharpDev Yes, another sync way to solve the problem would be fine. But I can't see any such possibility.

Comment: @SharpDev Why would you avoid canvas.measureText? I have noticed it has some problems, but I hoped there was a way to avoid them.

Comment: I would disagree with your `There is no need to create a "working example" for this.` you create a "working sample" not for you, but for others trying to reproduce the problem, the faster others can "see" your problem the faster you get an answer

Comment: @Leo Just append a div to the body of the document, requiring its max width and height to be 0 and overflow to be hidden... Then simply create and append a span with the text you need to the div. You can use the getBoundingClientRect() method on the span and that will give you the dimensions you need... For the most efficient use of this (depending on how many times you need to call this method) it may be easier to append both this div and span to initialize and then update the text and get the width once updated each time... Otherwise the speed is... Not completely awful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I've used in the past:

```
    tm = context.measureText(txt); // width is obvious "tm.width" 
    h = tm.actualBoundingBoxAscent + tm.actualBoundingBoxDescent
```

... and to be clear these values are for that text in that specific canvas, those values have no direct relation with other elements outside the canvas.
From the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics

> The TextMetrics interface represents the dimensions of a piece of text in the canvas; a TextMetrics instance can be retrieved using the CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText() method.

Try the code below see if that gets you closer to your goal.

```js
function fillText(ctx, x, y, txt, font) {
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.fillText(txt, x, y)
    const tm = ctx.measureText(txt);
    const h = tm.actualBoundingBoxAscent + tm.actualBoundingBoxDescent
    ctx.rect(x, y, tm.width, -h); 
    ctx.stroke();
    return tm;
} 

const canvas = document.getElementById("x");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = "red";

x = fillText(context, 10, 30, "HELLO", "20px monospace")
//console.log(x)
x = fillText(context, 10, 85, "WORLD", "60px monospace")
//console.log(x)
x = fillText(context, 120, 35, "123.456-7890", "40px monospace")
//console.log(x)
```

```html
<canvas id="x" width=600></canvas>
```

On this code I'm drawing some text and a rectangle around it with the values I get from measureText, as you can see the values match correctly